# why python multithreading runs like a single thread on macos?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a similiar and simple computation task with three different parameters. So I take this chance to test how much time I can save by using multithreading.

Here is my code:

```
import threading
import time
from Crypto.Hash import MD2

def calc_func(text):
    t1 = time.time()
    h = MD2.new()
    total = 10000000
    old_text =text
    for n in range(total):
        h.update(text)
        text = h.hexdigest()
    print(f"thread done: old_text={old_text} new_text={text}, time={time.time()-t1}sec")

def do_3threads():
    t0 = time.time()
    texts = ["abcd", "abcde", "abcdef"]
    ths = []
    for text in texts:
        th = threading.Thread(target=calc_func, args=(text,))
        th.start()
        ths.append(th)
    for th in ths:
        th.join()
    print(f"main done: {time.time()-t0}sec")

def do_single():
    texts = ["abcd", "abcde", "abcdef"]
    for text in texts:
        calc_func(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("=== 3 threads ===")
    do_3threads()
    print("=== 1 thread ===")
    do_single()
```

The result is astonishing, each thread is taking roughly 4x time it takes if single threaded:

```
=== 3 threads ===
thread done: old_text=abcdef new_text=e8f636b1893f12abe956dc019294e923, time=25.460321187973022sec
thread done: old_text=abcd new_text=0d6cae713809c923475ea50dbfbb2c13, time=25.47859835624695sec
thread done: old_text=abcde new_text=cd028131bc5e161671a1c91c62e80f6a, time=25.4807870388031sec
main done: 25.481309175491333sec
=== 1 thread ===
thread done: old_text=abcd new_text=0d6cae713809c923475ea50dbfbb2c13, time=6.393985033035278sec
thread done: old_text=abcde new_text=cd028131bc5e161671a1c91c62e80f6a, time=6.5472939014434814sec
thread done: old_text=abcdef new_text=e8f636b1893f12abe956dc019294e923, time=6.483690977096558sec
```

This is totally not what I expected. This task is obviously a CPU intensive task, so I expect that, with multithreading, each thread could just take around 6.5 seconds and the whole process takes slightly over that, instead it took actually ~25.5 seconds, even worse than single threaded mode, which is ~20seconds.

The environment is python 3.7.7, macos 10.15.5, CPU is 8-core Intel i9, 16G memory.

Can someone explain that to me? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Look into python's **GIL**: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock. That means that all the threads of a python process share the same CPU. If you want to utilize more CPUs you can use python multiprocessing: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: thank you @Daniser, this is very informative.

Answer (score 1):

> This task is obviously a CPU intensive task

Multithreading is not the proper tool for CPU bound tasks, but rather for something like network requests. This is because each Python process is limited to a single core due to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). All threads spawned by a process will run on the same core as the parent process.

Multiprocessing is what you are looking for, as it allows you to spawn multiple processes on, potentially, multiple cores.